# Tweepy StreamWatcher Example

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I'm just started playing with Tweepy and have it installed.  I've done basic oauth stuff with it, so I know that everything is good to go.

The problem I'm having is using this StreamWatcher example that I found a lot of people pointing to:

https://github.com/tweepy/examples/blob/master/streamwatcher.py

When I run it prompts me for my username and password and directly afterwards crashes with this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I'm stuck...

Comment: Example works fine for me, at which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
# page located at https://dev.twitter.com/apps (under "OAuth settings")
consumer_key="xxx"
consumer_secret="xxx"

access_token="xxx"
access_token_secret="xxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

...

stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, StreamWatcherListener(), timeout=None)
```